# Google App Engine: store uploaded file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have managed to create a file in GCS in the post method of a webapp2 handler of a Google App Engine application. I can't see how to copy the content of a posted file in the file created in GCS.
Here is my code

```
 inFile =  self.request.POST.multi['file'].file
 gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                    'w',
                    content_type='text/plain',
                    options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                             'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
                    retry_params=write_retry_params)
  while 1:
        line = inFile.readline()
        if not line: break
        gcs_file.write(line)
  gcs_file.close()
```

At the end of the process the file in GCS is 0 byte

**UPDATE**
There is a reason why I am not using the blobstore. When using the Blobstore you have to create an url and sand it back to the client. it is the client that performs the actual upload. 
INSTEAD I need to encrypt the file on the server before to put it in the GCS. Thus I need to receive the file from the client, encrypt it on the server and store it in the GCS.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not writing the whole file at once?  Also, have you verified, maybe with `logging`, that you've properly received the file with the content length you expect from the POST?

Comment: Ah, I remember you from your prev question. You seem dead set on uploading to your webapp2 handler. Just stop. You are doing this wrong. USE THE BLOBSTORE.  Yes. You use the blobstore to get the file to GCS. You really should just read up the whole blobstore overview. I'm not sure you are going to get any help here if you don't do the basic steps.

Comment: @Zachary I have already checked the file is uploaded by verifying self.request.POST.multi['file'].filename actually returns the expected string. I hope this means the content is uploaded as well. I have also tried gcs_file.write(inFile.read()) but still get 0 bytes

Comment: @Zachary I have verified the byte is correctly uploaded as the uploaded size is correct. But there something wrong with that loop as it enters only once (and the readline returns null). How should I read the file contents?

Comment: @Sindico: Hm, you haven't shown creating `filename` (with the correct bucket name), but if you're getting a file at all, albeit empty, then I assume `filename` is correct. And you've attempted to just write a static string, e.g., `gcs_file.write('some boring text')`?

Comment: Looks like you've copied the sample code here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class?

Comment: @user2771609: "I'm not sure you are going to get any help here if you don't do the basic steps."... Google provides this API, so, it's valid. Even if Sindico didn't really need to bypass Blobstore and just wanted to do it this way, this is still a solution that's well enough (for GAE) documented.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung I'm pointing out that there is a better solution to his problem if he breaks out of this mold of uploading to his handler. He is working under some misconceptions. His update to the questions displays it clearly. He seems to believe that encrypting the file in his handler is somehow better than sending the file to the blobstore then encrypting it and saving to GCS. I think a good answer should point out the misconceptions that are apparent in the question, instead of letting him go down a suboptimal path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully POST'ed a file to GCS with the following method:

```
def post(self):
    write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
    filename = '/{MY-BUCKET-NAME}/static.txt'

    gcs_file = gcs.open(
        filename,
        'w',
        content_type='text/plain',
        options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                 'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
        retry_params=write_retry_params)

    inFile = self.request.POST.multi['file'].file
    while 1:
        line = inFile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        gcs_file.write(line)
        logging.info('Wrote line: {}'.format(line))

    gcs_file.close()
```

Here's the little log message from Console:

```
I 09:20:32.979 2015-05-07  200      84 B   1.13s /static
    76.176.106.172 - - [07/May/2015:09:20:32 -0700] "POST /static HTTP/1.1" 200 84 - "curl/7.37.1" "{MY-APP}" ms=1131 cpu_ms=1355 cpm_usd=0.000009 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117cee89e66d34a42c5bbe3cf2b0bb06b5 app_engine_release=1.9.20
I 09:20:32.832 Wrote line: stack
I 09:20:32.833 Wrote line: overflow
```

Here's the `test.txt` file I uploaded:

```
stack
overflow
```

And the cURL command I used:

```
curl -F"file=@/Users/{name}/test.txt" http://{MY-APP}/videostatic
```

If you're still getting 0 bytes from `readline()` or `read()` I'm going to have to assume that your client is not sending the correct multipart message.

Comment: @Sindico: you're very welcome. I'm very curious, what was your fix?

Comment: I made a silly mistake. The encryption left the input file at the EOF position.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to upload a file to GCS in a Google App Engine application seems to be to use the blobstore with a gcs bucket backing.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

There are many reasons why you should not upload directly to your webapp2 handler.

1. Limitations in file size.
2. Limitations in request duration.
3. Additional charges since you are billed when your handler is running.

to name a few...

**UPDATE**

To address the update to the question: You should STILL upload to the blobstore. Do this in 3 steps:

1. Upload to blobstore.
2. Read from blobstore, and write encrypted to GCS.
3. Delete from blobstore.